# Dart Fletch can't unzip SD Card image

Tags: dart

I can't unzip my Fletch raspberry Pi image with **platforms/raspberry-pi2/flash-sd-card** :

```
Downloading SD card image
Downloading: DONE                             
Decompressing SD card image.
FAILURE: Failed to decompress SD card image
/tmp/flash_sd_cardo7mHn4/fletch_raspbian.img:  write error (disk full?).
Continue? (y/n/^C)
warning:  /tmp/flash_sd_cardo7mHn4/fletch_raspbian.img is probably truncated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On manjaro Linux i couldn't unzip the file in **/tmp/**, i had to set a custom download path with **--tmp-dir**:

```
platforms/raspberry-pi2/flash-sd-card --tmp-dir $HOME
```

(Note that you may have to delete these temp files yourself once the process done.)